# C++/Linux, share objects in memory between applications

Tags: c++, vector, shared-memory

I have one application which generates quite a bit of data and I would like it to be available for another C++ application to access. Platform is RHEL5, g++ if that matters.

Previously, the way I have done this is by writing the data out to /dev/shm (basically a linux memory drive) and then having the other application read it from there.

However, this seems pretty inefficient as there's an ofstream, then an ifstream, and reloading the data into memory. Furthermore, storing the data as text files in memory seems like it would take more space than just keeping it as memory (although I'm not 100% sure this is true).

The data I want to share is in the form of

```
vector< vector<struct> > mydata;
```

I would like the other application to be able to do something like

```
mydata.at(ii).back()
```

to retrieve the data it needs. There is actually going to be quite a bit of data in mydata. If I were to print it out into a CSV format file, it would be maybe 10GB. The server I am working on has 24GB of memory which should be enough to handle this.

Furthermore, this retrieval would occur as the first application is adding more entries into mydata (so maybe there are potential race conditions?).

Is there a way in C++ to share vector< vector > mydata; between two applications? If so, what would be the best implementation to use? I would prefer to avoid third party libraries if possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with pipes?

Comment: It doesn't handle any synchronization, but you can use `mmap` to share memory across applications. And you can use `placement new` to put the vector into the memory provided by `mmap`, but it seems like you might have to write your own allocator to keep all the elements of these vectors within that chunk of memory.

This sort of access would probably be much faster than using `fstream`, but the devil's in the details.

Comment: Hey could you please share how did you implement using boost libraries ?? I am also going through a similar issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may *prefer* to avoid 3rd-party libraries, but the best quick solution is there.  Try out Boost.Interprocess.  It provides shared-memory-safe containers (like vector) as well as easy interfaces to work with.  It is also one of the header-only libraries, which makes it easier to integrate than a few of the other libraries.

See the link here for the doc on the latest version: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

There's quite a few examples there too.  It should give you a good quick overview of what it's capable of.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in C++ to share vector< vector > mydata; between two
>   applications? If so, what would be the best implementation to use? I
>   would prefer to avoid third party libraries if possible.

By applications, if you mean processes, then the answer is no, data structures cannot be shared between two processes. For sharing data between processes, one has to use shared memory (as you identified). (One can do inter process communication with messages, but your use case is probably not suitable for that.

Would you consider using **threads**? That way, you can share `mydata` between two threads of execution. You would need a `mutex` to synchronize access to the shared data.

If you are using C++11, then you can do it entirely with C++ standard library `std::thread`. If not, than you may have to use the POSIX thread library `pthreads`.

> Furthermore, this retrieval would occur as the first application is
>   adding more entries into mydata (so maybe there are potential race
>   conditions?).

Not exactly, it is possible to allow multiple reader threads to progress in parallel by using [reader-writer locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock), but when the writer thread starts modifying the shared object, all the reader threads has to hold off, otherwise there will be inconsistencies and lots of other problems.